# PDT 2.2 +xDebug unable debug as php script

Tags: php

PDT 2.2+Xdebug work awesome in "debug as web page", but when "debug as script" is show error.

> You cannot use both -n and -c switch. Use -h for help.

But i pretty sure the php.ini is well and access by xDebug.

Below is the xdebug section in php.ini

```
[XDebug]
;; Only Zend OR (!) XDebug
zend_extension_ts="\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.1-5.2-vc6.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.1.38
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
```